# linker not working in Xcode -CUDA error

Tags: cuda, linker

```
Ld /Users/pranaytare/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XcodeTest-esjkvjumeojbilbyksjnrsvsvsiz/Build/Products/Debug/XcodeTest normal i386
    cd /Users/pran/Downloads/XcodeTest
    setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.8
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk -L/Users/pranaytare/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XcodeTest-esjkvjumeojbilbyksjnrsvsvsiz/Build/Products/Debug -L/usr/local/cuda/lib -L/Users/pranaytare/Downloads/XcodeTest -F/Users/pranaytare/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XcodeTest-esjkvjumeojbilbyksjnrsvsvsiz/Build/Products/Debug -filelist /Users/pranaytare/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XcodeTest-esjkvjumeojbilbyksjnrsvsvsiz/Build/Intermediates/XcodeTest.build/Debug/XcodeTest.build/Objects-normal/i386/XcodeTest.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker /usr/local/cuda/lib -mmacosx-version-min=10.8 -lcudart -lcuda -lcudart -o /Users/pranaytare/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XcodeTest-esjkvjumeojbilbyksjnrsvsvsiz/Build/Products/Debug/XcodeTest

ld: file not found: @rpath/CUDA.framework/Versions/A/CUDA for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocati
```

Comment: try launching it on device. The error says that it can not find the CUDA framework for simulator architecture (i386)

Comment: @medvedNick: What? This is a linking error during an application build inside Xcode. How or what is "launching it on device" in this context?

Comment: @talonmies well, I need to read questions more properly :\ I did not notice the target is Mac, not iOS. However, on iOS, if you build app for simulator (which is i386) with armv7 version of static library, you will get the same error while building.

Comment: `clang` is not officially supported unless you are using cuda 5.5  You may wish to carefully follow the steps in the [mac getting started document](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-getting-started-guide-for-mac-os-x/index.html)